# what is the actual word looking similar to 戸感

Tags: translation, words, meaning

I've seen the word 戸感 (or something similar) in a few visual novels, and i was able to find it also in some lyrics when i searched for it on [google](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E6%88%B8%E6%84%9F%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&hl=ja#), but i couldn't find it neither on [jdic](http://nihongo.monash.edu.au/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?1MUJ%E6%88%B8%E6%84%9F), [goo](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/all/%E6%88%B8%E6%84%9F/m0u/) nor [alc](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E6%88%B8%E6%84%9F), and trying to understand it by the meaning of kanji doesn't make much sense...

Comment: Is it not「[戸惑]{とまど}う」or「[戸惑]{とまど}い」? (感vs惑)

Comment: that would answer my question, it fits the situations i've seen the word in, and on the font/font size i read visual novels these two (感 vs 惑) look pretty much the same - if you post it as an answer i'll mark as accepted one, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's the verb [戸惑]{とまど}う, "to be puzzled / confused / disoriented". [戸惑]{とまど}い is its noun form.

Comment: この歌詞の「戸感ってる？」はtypoですね・・・　http://mojim.com/twy132621x1x2.htm